# How does control flow remain in the async method scope after it has returned the result? Is this similar to closure for variables?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

In the below code, 42 is printed to the Console before "Almost done" is. Since 42 has already been returned, how is the control still in `AsyncCheck`? I understand that if the task has not completed at 'await', it will  return the control but here I have an explicit return statement, so I'm having some trouble getting my head around this.

```
async static Task<int> AsyncCheck()
{
   await Task.Factory.StartNew( async () => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start awesome work");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Almost done");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Ok, done!");
    });

   return 42;
}

async static void AsyncCall()
{
    int result = await AsyncCheck();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

I am using 'async void' to just check this sample.

Comment: Try `await await Task.Factory.StartNew(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`. You should be using `Task.Run`. `Task.Factory.StartNew` came in .Net 4.0 without `async-await` in mind. You can still use it, but unless you have a good reason, `Task.Run` is a safer alternative.

Instead of returning a `Task` it returns a `Task<Task>` that you need to unwrap before awaiting:

```
Task<Task> task = Task.Factory.StartNew( async () => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start awesome work");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Almost done");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Ok, done!");
});
Task unwrappedTask = task.Unwrap();
await unwrappedTask
```

Without it you're not really waiting for you lambda to complete. All your doing is using a `ThreadPool` thread to fire up this async method.

Basically you are executing your lambda in parallel on a different thread while your code flow continues on. That's why you see "42" before "Almost done"

Comment: Thanks, this now makes the flow control clear. However, how is this now not blocking at 'await Task.Delay'? Control is not returned to the calling statement. I introduced a new Console.WriteLine just before I print the result and it is not printed while it is waiting. Does await block?

Comment: Certainly your explanation of having to unwrap the Task is correct. However saying StartNew "doesn't support" async/await is a strange statement. With the addition of the shortcuts via Task.Run it is primarily for more advanced scenarios.

Comment: @Kodathon It doesn't actually block, but it make it seems as if it did. When the first `await` is reached the rest of the method is scheduled as a continuation after the awaited task and the continuation is returned to the caller which may do the same.

Comment: @mikez It came before async-await and wasn't meant for it. It has no explicilt support for it. You can still use it, but you mostly shouldn't.

Comment: Sure it came before but it is still usable. The primary case that isn't handled well by StartNew is async delegates, as we have here, not async/await in general.

Comment: @mikez What use does `StartNew` serve other than accepting delegates?

Comment: @i3arnon:Ok, so the reason it isn't doing is due to async void - if I change it to return a Task then it continues from the point AsyncCall was invoked. async void bit me in a snippet as well ! Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: @i3arnon I'm not sure what you are getting at but the distinction is between async and sync delegates. `Run` merely has overloads that do the desired Unwrap above for you which was made a much more common scenario with the addition of async delegates. A sync delegate would have behaved as intended.

Comment: @mikez a sync delegate has nothing to do with `async-await`. But nevermind, I already changed the wording 30 mins ago.

Comment: The fine-grained control you get with `Task.Factory.StartNew` is for "special cases" when dealing with custom `Task.Scheduler ` or a wanting to hint the factory you want a new thread instead of one from the thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

Let's desugar! You have

```
async static Task<int> AsyncCheck()
{
   await Task.Factory.StartNew( async () => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start awesome work");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Almost done");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Ok, done!");
    });

   return 42;
}

async static void AsyncCall()
{
    int result = await AsyncCheck();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This is turned in to the following by the compiler:

```
static Task<int> AsyncCheck()
{
   Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start awesome work");
        Task d1 = Task.Delay(1000);
        d1.ContinueWith(t1 => {
          Console.WriteLine("Almost done");
          Task t2 = Task.Delay(1000);
          t2.ContinueWith( tt2 => {
            Console.WriteLine("Ok, done!");
          }
        }
    });
   //no dependecies on t, so just return straight away
   return Task.FromResult(42);
}

static void AsyncCall()
{
    Task<int> result = AsyncCheck();
    result.ContinueWith( t => {
      Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
    })
}
```

`ContinueWith` will run it's body once the task completes. This should make the control flow clear.

Comment: +1 for desugar! all of this async await without understanding what was going on behind the scenes gave me diabetes